# Deleted my root account from /etc/passwd file for testing in Centos7.3

Tags: linux, root, passwd

I deleted my root account line from the file `/etc/passwd` and unable to boot into Rescue Mode and Emergency Mode.

How can I recover the root user back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enter into rescue mode.

After entering into rescue mode with a Live USB, run this command as root.

If you have installed your OS with `/etc` on a different partition instead of having all the filesystem's in one partition, mount the `/etc/` partition of your Centos install onto a folder, for this example I will use `/dev/sda2`.

```
mkdir /mnt/etc
mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/etc 
echo 'root::0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash' >> /mnt/etc/passwd
```

If you have don't have your `/etc/` on a different disk, mount your Centos installation's root directory(`/`).

```
mkdir /mnt/root
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/root 
echo 'root::0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash' >> /mnt/root/etc/passwd
```

Comment: Have you tried that? (I haven't.) Wouldn't `root::0` be better if you omit setting a password?

Comment: My bad, completely forgot about that, also yes, edited to `root::0`

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just boot into single user mode?

Comment: On the other hand, if the original poster just deleted the root line in `/etc/passwd`, wouldn't the original encrypted password be intact in `/etc/shadow`, so `root:x:0` would be ok after all.

Comment: Man I'm trying to make it so I can't login as root but i can't .-.

Comment: I get the feeling this isn't the only problem with their system.

Comment: @Johan Myréen Yes. For login purposes root is still mapped even when its not in passwd. But this does not apply to other usernames.

Comment: That command will write to `/etc/passwd` of the root files system i.e. the USB device.

Comment: @Hunter.S.Thompson I add the root line in /etc/passwd line. but i am unable to login into the system. The system stucks at the GUI loading screen sign which just appear before the login screen

Comment: @zahid updated answer, try that out.

Comment: @johan I manually delete the root account information from /etc/passwd file then I restart my VM and I am unable to login into system

Comment: @Hunter.S.Thompson I solved my problem. Thanks for help

Comment: @zahid Don't forget to mark it as complete, another user might be able to use this answer later on. Also, thanks for the edit, I will be removing the link because link only answer's are not ideal.

Comment: @Hunter.S.Thompson still there is slight mistake in your at mount option.
mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/etc/etc/passwd  beacuse first etc is directory you make and 2nd etc is actual configuration file.

Comment: Read carefully @zahid, that option is for if your `/etc/` is in a different disk, in which case you would be in the directory itself.

Comment: @Hunter.S.Thompson I read it carefully     
mkdir /mnt/etc12  
mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/etc12   
echo 'root::0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash' >> /mnt/etc12/etc/passwd   
Hope you can understand

Comment: @zahid When you are installing, you can choose to have your `/etc/` directory on a different disk, when you mount that disc onto `/etc/` you are in the folder `/etc/` already. So if your `/etc/` is on a different disk when you mount `/mnt/etc/` onto that disk you would already be in the `/etc/` folder, in which case you don't need the extra `/mnt/etc/etc/`.

Answer (score 0):

If the root passwd information is stored in shadow then all you need is to boot normally and run sudo under a sudo user.

```
sudo nano /etc/passwd
```